# SAXParser how to ignore white space in element text

Tags: sax, saxparser

i have SAXParser to parse xml feed, for some element there are whitespace characters embedded like

```
 <category>Beauty, Spas, & Salons</category>
```

and the parser only extract 'Beauty' from 'category' instead of 'Beauty, Spas, & Salons', how can i force it to extract the whole string? thanks

Comment: This XML is invalid and is giving you problems - the ampersand _must be escaped_: ```<category>Beauty, Spas, &amp; Salons</category>```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parser is almost certainly giving you the whole string but it is over multiple calls to characters().  characters() will be called any number of times to deliver the contents of an element; it could be one character at a time.  You need to keep a String (or StringBuilder...) and add to it each time characters() is called.  You don't know you have the whole element content until endElement() is called.